# Am i in the right direction on this probability/random distribution question?

Tags: probability, random

To improve the operation in the control tower of an airport, air traffic control engineers are assessing the delay due to taxi-out time, which is the duration between pushback and takeoff. suppose that the combined taxi-out and takeoff time for commercial jets is a random variable X with mean of 8.5 minutes and a standard deviation of 2.5 minutes. What is the probability that for 36 jets on a given runway the total taxi-out and takeoff time will be between 275 and 320 minutes?

My attempt is shown below. Any corrections and help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks good. Now you have to find out the values for Φ(−2.066) and Φ(0.933)-by looking in the table of the standard normal distribution. You can use the relation Φ(−2.066)=1−Φ(2.066)

Comment: Ok Thanks!!!!!!